# Why do I need a space in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match either the `Eu` or `U.s.` using PHP's `preg_match_all`.
Given the following sentence:

> The Eu is better than the U.s. in certain ways.

I can match both Eu and U.s. if I use:

```
preg_match_all("/\b(Eu|U\.s\. )\b/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

but not if I use:

```
preg_match_all("/\b(Eu|U\.s\.)\b/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Why do I need a space after the . in order for my regex to work?

Comment: \b matches a word boundary. for instance a comma, period or space. Since you also have a boundary character you're matching against it's causing you problems. Are you trying to find that string anywhere in your code or at the end. Can you give an example string that you're matching against?

Comment: It may be in the middle of a sentence as a word or it could have a comma after it.  For example "In the U.s., we think that the U.s. is (Hey, not going to get political here: write whatever you like!)".  In my previous sentence, both of the U.s. should be matched.

Comment: just use withou `\b` oO?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I'd match the Eu in Europe which I don't want to do...

Comment: You can use a negative lookahead as final boundary: [`\b(?:Eu|U\.s\.)(?!\w)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/Z7F5V7/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is
   a    word character(\w).
2. After the last character in the string, if the last    character is
   a    word character.
3. Between two characters in the string,    where one is a word
   character and the other is not a word character.

so in your case which is number 3 the U.s. bounded like this:  **\b U \b .\b s \b .**

Comment: right. see example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f435a11609606cf7f8d4f5e330d443989911c5b

Answer (score 1):

What @mmta41 said. Here is a test:

```
$re = '/(eu|\bU\b.\bs\b.)/mi';
$str = 'U.s.,u.S., U.S. , u.s.. ,Eu,eU, EU , eu.Europe UseuUs Europe';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f435a11609606cf7f8d4f5e330d443989911c5b